# wordpress- How to give conformation popup message in custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to delete items only after conformation.

So i need popup to ask conformation that " Are you sure "'Yes' or 'No'

```
 * [OPTIONAL] Return array of bulk actions if has any
 *
 * @return array


function get_bulk_actions()
{
    $actions = array(
        'delete' => 'Delete'
    );
    return $actions;
}
```

---

- [OPTIONAL] This method processes bulk actions
- it can be outside of class
- it can not use wp_redirect coz there is output already
- in this example we are processing delete action
- message about successful deletion will be shown on page in next part

  ```
  function process_bulk_action()
  {
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'abc; // do not forget about tables prefix

  if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
  $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
  if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);
  if (!empty($ids)) {
  $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN($ids)");
  }
  }
  }
  ```

---

- List page handler
- This function renders our custom table
- we display message about successful deletion

  ```
       function custom_table_example_persons_page_handler()
       {
       global $wpdb;
       $table = new Custom_Table_Example_List_Table();
       $table->prepare_items();
       $message = '';
       if ('delete' === $table->current_action()) {
       $message = '<div class="updated below-h2" id="message"><p>' .
       sprintf(__('Items deleted: %d', 'custom_table_example'), count($_REQUEST['id'])) . '</p></div>';
       }
       ?>
  ```